# Gaussian Elimination of a Singular Matrix

Tags: c++, c, matrix, linear-algebra

So i've been struggling to find code which can solve a set of simultaneous equations and also handle possibilities of Infinite Solutions, i.e. a singular Matrix. From all the sample code Gaussian Elimination in C that i've encountered the problem arises when dividing by zero in one of the steps for row reduction. Surely there must be some numerical ways to counter this problem.

Comment: If you get a divide-by-zero, then you have a singular matrix.  Simple!

Comment: For underconstrained systems, you can just use the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse to find the one with minimal norm.

Comment: Well the goal isnt to detect a singular matrix its to be able to get the solution set from it.I'm not very familiar with the Moore Penrose pseudoinverse but from a youtube search it works well for overdetermined systems does that also hold true for undertermined cases i.e. with infinite solutions?

Comment: I have a number of algorithms books describing various Gaussian elimination algorithms and all have trigger steps for stopping without division by zero.

Comment: Are there any available online preferably with open source code for the algorithms?

Comment: [Click here to submit feedback about your question-asking experience.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129)

Comment: You can use pivoted QR decomposition (of the transpose of the system matrix) or the SVD to find the solvable part of the system. Which can also be described as computing or applying the pseudo-inverse. This will give the solution of minimal norm and minimal error. Try not only youtube for mathematical information, use also wikipedia, planetmath, mathworld, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Gaussian elimination[1] does not work on singular matrices. As you noticed numerically this usually leads to devision by zero or some other problem. If you suspect that a the matrix you want to diagonalize might be singular (or numerically close to singular) you should check out Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) which either provides you with the inverse matrix or something close. A nice resource is Numerical Recipes[1] or GSL[2] if you want to look into the how and why.

[1] http://www.haoli.org/nr/bookcpdf.html (Chap. 2.1)
[2] http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: Well my ultimate goal is to extract a solution from the set of infinite solutions such that the solution is Non-zero or negative (if such a solution exists in the space). So just detecting for singularities is not that important. I should add some context I'm trying to write a Chemical equation Balancer program and many of the equations when placed into a matrix yield underdetermined solutions.

Comment: I have no idea on how to calculate chemical equations so maybe I am wrong about this. It sounds as if what you are interested in is not quite computable using numerical methods. Bear in mind that computers are not really good at understanding context and therefore cannot understand (numerically) inf/inf ~ O(1) or something like that. It might well be that you would fare better with a tool for symbolic calculations like Mathematica (I used it at university so that's what I know). Maybe programming in Maxima or Lisp would work too.